# Where to manage domain for Office365 (Mail) and Wordpress/Magento

Tags: microsoft-office-365, web-hosting

I currently inherited a installation running its own server for hosting (Wordpress/Magento) and also e-mail. E-Mails are used within the organization via Outlook (non 365) and imap.

The plan is to switch to Office 365 (as we will also use Dynamics 365 CRM in the future) and I'd like to switch over from the self-hosted emails to using Office 365.

I am wondering now, what is the better solution.

1. Point the domain to Office365, and then set up the webserver IP via Office 365, or
2. Keep the domain management outside of Office365 and just point the mail servers to Office365.

I was trying to find some best practice for that but wasn't able to find anything helpful.

Any pointers are appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is largely subjective and opinion based.

That being said, I prefer option 2.

Comment: Thank you, would you mind to elaborate why you would prefer 2? My experience with domains/mail is, that out of all parts mails are the most complicated to setup. So putting the domain to microsoft and automate the mail setup would be less failure prone, than the other way round. Wrong thinking?

Comment: I prefer option 2 because I prefer to manage the DNS myself and not put it into the hands of the service provider, whether that be related to Office 365, Web hosting, email hosting, whatever.